# How to save image state after app closes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

In iOS app, users have the ability to change the colour of a `UIImage`. When they click a `UIButton`, the colour changes. However, when I exit the app, I have the following problems:

1. I recently started getting this when I close the app:
   PAC evaluation error: `NSURLErrorDomain: -1003`
2. When I return to the app, the UIImage reverts to the standard colour

I'm not to skilled at doing things within the app delegate but I'm sure I have to do something within the:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
```

This is what I have in my `UIViewController` button function:

```
myImage.image = UIImage(named: "newImage.png")!

ViewController().myImage.image = UIImage(named: "newImage.png")
```

I tried to add this in the `applicationWillTerminate` function in the app delegate but no dice.

When I change the color of the `UIImage`, then close the app, the app should not crash. Instead, the app should be able to reopen with the new image as the UIImageView.

Comment: You can use UserDefaults to save colors of image.

Comment: I looked into that however I’m not sure exactly what to set and for what key

Comment: rmaddy said not to save images in UserDefaults since it’s not for that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: save image in core data

Comment: CoreData is total overkill and nonsense for this! Save the [PNG representation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata) in your app's caches directory (see [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407726-urls))

Comment: Why don't you save the color and after kill the app again apply same color, BTW its up to you what kind of application you have and what is your requirement, consider image as normal variable when you kill app it will lost so you need to save it in proper way according to your requirement, saving in documents also a good option.